# C++ Declare Aligned Storage for Placement-New

Tags: c++, c++17, memory-alignment, placement-new

I've created some templates in order to create aligned-storage capable of being used for placement-new:

```
template<typename T, typename... U>
constexpr size_t max_alignof()
{
    if constexpr (sizeof...(U))
        return std::max(alignof(T), max_alignof<U...>());
    else
        return alignof(T);
}

template<typename T, typename... U>
constexpr size_t max_sizeof()
{
    if constexpr (sizeof...(U))
        return std::max(sizeof(T), max_sizeof<U...>());
    else
        return sizeof(T);
}

// This isn't allowed by the standard, but illustrates my goal
template <typename... T>
using aligned_buffer_t = alignas(max_alignof<T...>()) char[max_sizeof<T...>()];

// Types A, B are classes that I want to placement-new
aligned_buffer_t<A, B> buffer;
A* = new (&buffer[0]) A();
A->~A();
B* = new (&buffer[0]) B();
B->~B();
```

How can I accomplish the above, without having to re-type the template parameters to `aligned_buffer_t`?  The best solution I could come up with to accomplish this was the following macro:

```
#define ALIGNED_BUFFER_T(VAR, ...)\
    alignas(max_alignof<__VA_ARGS__>()) char VAR[max_sizeof<__VA_ARGS__>()]
ALIGNED_BUFFER_T(buffer, A, B);
```

Is the above possible without using macros, and without using the deprecated `std::aligned_storage`?  The reason I am interested is because one of the class lists is auto-generated, so the code I tried to write was:

```
aligned_buffer_t<
#include "GeneratedClassList.hpp"
> buffer;
```

I couldn't figure out any syntax using macros that would enable such a construct.

Comment: If you don't want to retype `A`, `B`, how are you going to select which class to insert?

Comment: I don't understand the macro example - you did type A and B explicitly in the invocation. What's the difference?

Comment: Why don't you just use `std::variant`? Why bother with placement new and alignment if you can use an existing class?

Comment: @ALX23z The `std::variant` idea is intriguing.  In my specific case, all of the values implement interface `Base`, so I could just write `std::variant<std::monostate, #include "GeneratedClassList.hpp"> buffer; Base *obj = nullptr; obj = &buffer.emplace<A>(...);`.  That is a very clean solution!  I'll write up an answer if I don't see one from you in the next few days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by ALX23z, my proposed approach was just a roundabout way of reimplementing `std::variant`.  The solution therefore is simply to change the code to:

```
std::variant<std::monostate, A, B> buffer;
A *a = &buffer.emplace<A>();
// Do stuff with a
B *b = &buffer.emplace<B>();
// Do stuff with b
```